# Portably supporting relaxed range-for-loop

Tags: c++, foreach, range, c++17, forward-compatibility

C++17 will (probably) [relax the definition of the range for loop](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0184r0.html), allowing `end()` to return a distinct type (e.g. a sentinel):

```
struct MyRange {
    struct Sentinel {};
    int* begin();
    Sentinel end();
};
bool operator!=(int*, MyRange::Sentinel);
```

Currently the only compilers that support this are gcc 6.1 and clang 4.0+ ([example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/2ovftIsadkV3nJut)) ([example of error message](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8DrEkn1XIfnRjnn8)). If I'm writing a range type where a sentinel would be more efficient for the end type, how can I detect whether the compiler supports relaxed range for? I can't see any discussion of this in P0184R0 (linked above); will a feature test macro be provided?

Further questions:

- If there is a way to detect compiler support, is it safe (for the library) to change the return type of my `end()` member function? Do I need e.g. to make my sentinel implicitly convertible to my iterator type?
- Conversely, for pre-C++17 compilers is it worth exposing my sentinel under a different name (e.g. `sentinel()`)? Can pre-C++17 algorithms efficiently use `[begin(), sentinel())` or is it not worth the additional code?

Comment: Per [P0096R3](http://wg21.link/p0096r3), you can check whether `__cpp_range_based_for` is greater than or equal to 201603.

Comment: @cpplearner ah, of course. Please make that an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [P0096R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0096r3.html), you can check whether `__cpp_range_based_fo‌​r` is greater than or equal to 201603. Of course, Visual Studio does not support *any* of the feature test macros, so you'll have to check its versioning separately. They shipped support for it in VS2015 Update 3, but along with most other C++17 support, you have to use the `/std:c++latest` switch.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why sentinels are efficient rarely has to do with the internal state of the sentinel.

So one approach is to give your `Sentinel` enough internal state to generate the iterator version of itself.

Even in C++14 with uniform end-begin `for(:)` loops and algorithms that insist on identical start/finish iterator types, hand-written algorithms or loops could use your sentinel and gain efficiency.

A library like [Boost.Config](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/config/doc/html/index.html) is usually your best bet if you want maximal coverage, but a C++17 feature-detection set has not been published as of this date (that I can find).

There is, as far as I can tell, no way to SFINAE-detect the existence of `for(:)` loops that accept different begin/end iterator types.  (I could imagine something `constexpr` noexcept something hacks, but that is beyond my skill.)

Detecting if `<algorithms>` accept sentinel end iterators can probably be done with SFINAE.  But I am uncertain even if C++17 has sentinel-ized `<algorithms>` or even intends to; ranges-v3 is supposed to handle the rework of that.